# Typescript Service not working with an err of block scope variable 'place' used before its declaration

Tags: typescript, service

```
import {Place} from "../models/place";
import {Location} from "../models/location";

export class PlacesService {
     private places: Place[] = [];


     addPlace(title: string,
              description: string,
              location: Location,
              base64Image: string){
         ***let place = new place(title,description,location,base64Image);***
          this.places.push(place);

     }

     loadPlaces(){
          return this.places.slice();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
let place = new place
    ^^^^^       ^^^^^
```

throws you an error, because you want to create an instance of `place` which is declared as a variable inside the constructor and you doesn't have initialized it. You model name is `Place` (first letter to uppercase), not `place`.

```
let place = new Place(...)
```